# how to change Value to something specific and not add to it?

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox, roblox-studio

When I want to set the currency to "Chara" nothing happens. What to do? Here's the script:

```
local leaderstats = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit and hit.Parent and hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        leaderstats.Character.Value = "Chara"???
        wait(3)
    end
end)
```

Help pls.

I tried to make my "Character" currency become "Chara", but nothing happens.

Comment: Where do you create the Leaderstats? Is `Character` a [StringValue](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/StringValue) object?